# How do I select the max date from a union of two tables?

Tags: t-sql

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM 
(
    select max(updatedtimestamp) from db1.dbo.policyrepresentationcache with(nolock)
    UNION
    select max(updatedtimestamp) from db2.dbo.policyrepresentationcache with(nolock)
    ) 
ORDER BY updatedtimestamp
```

I'm running into syntax errors here and im not sure how to set it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just missing an alias for the table produced by the union.  I've aliased it as **a** below.

```
SELECT TOP 1 a.updatedtimestamp FROM
(
     select max(updatedtimestamp) as updatedtimestamp  
     from db1.dbo.policyrepresentationcache with(nolock)
     UNION
     select max(updatedtimestamp) 
     from db2.dbo.policyrepresentationcache with(nolock)
) a
ORDER BY a.updatedtimestamp
```

Comment: I've double checked spelling - did you make sure to include the body of the union statement?  Notice I aliased the first column in the union statement so you could include it in the order by.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 Temp.* FROM 
(
    select max(updatedtimestamp) from db1.dbo.policyrepresentationcache with(nolock)
    UNION
    select max(updatedtimestamp) from db2.dbo.policyrepresentationcache with(nolock)
    ) AS Temp
ORDER BY Temp.updatedtimestamp
```